# Click and a floating component sliding down

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-bootstrap

I want to make a function that looks like Angular Material Datepicker: click a button, and a small component slides down and floats above other HTML elements.
In this component, there will be some input/radio and a confirm button, once clicked, the value will be brought back to HTML.

The biggest problem is that I'm not sure how to achieve "a small component sliding down and floating above another HTML element", which keyword I can use.

Any hint is appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this more of a CSS question then? See [MDN: CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) - also see [MDN: CSS positioning context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#positioning_contexts)